# Setting RabbitMQ additional configs via celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have been reading about [Delivery Acknowledgement Timeout](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout) in RabbitMQ and how this is controlled by an additional configuration in rabbitmq via the **consumer_timeout** variable. When using Redis as broker for celery, you can easily set **visibility_timeout** in the celery [broker transport options](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-broker_transport_options) configuration. For example

```
celery_app = Celery("my_app")
celery_app.conf.broker_transport_options = {"visibility_timeout": 3600}
```

So far I could not find any documentation on how to do the same for setting **consumer_timeout** for RabbitMQ. I could only find how to set it up in the rabbitmq.config file - which I do not have access - so I was wondering if it is possible to add this configuration via celery.

I have tried (* 1000 because it is in ms) but I do not think it is working.

```
celery_app.conf.broker_transport_options = {"consumer_timeout": 3600 * 1000}
```

I am using Celery > 5 and rabbitmq 3.9.

Comment: Hi @jpsca1293, have you found any workaround? I am facing the exact same issue :(

Comment: Hi @Shivanshu, I have changed my rabbitmq version to 3.8.11 instead, seems to work for me.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Not sure how to set it, seems `visibility_timeout` not working with rabitmq.  If there are any issues with rabitmq server, celery re-running the same tasks over and over again indefinitely.

Comment: @jpsca1293, did you get any other option to set for rabbitmq ? I want to set the timeout option.